# Pandas: How to convert a 10-min interval timeseries into a dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series similar to:

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(60),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',periods=60, freq='2h'))
```

Is there an easy way to make it so that the row index is dates and the column index is the hour?

Basically I am trying to convert from a time-series into a dataframe.

Comment: Your question title refers to 10 minute intervals, but your example has a 2 hour frequency.  If you really mean 10 minutes, do you want the data aggregated into hours?

Comment: No that was a mistake on my part. I would just like the time series turned into a dataframe and the row index to be dates and the columns to be the 10 min data. The true data is 10 min data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a slicker way to do things than the way I reach for, but I'd make a flat frame first and then pivot.  Something like

```
>>> ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',periods=10000, freq='10min'))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ts.index.date, "time": ts.index.time, "data": ts.values})
>>> df = df.pivot("date", "time", "data")
```

This produces too large a frame to paste, but looking the top left corner:

```
>>> df.iloc[:5, :5]
time        00:00:00  00:10:00  00:20:00  00:30:00  00:40:00
date                                                        
2000-01-01 -0.180811  0.672184  0.098536 -0.687126 -0.206245
2000-01-02  0.746777  0.630105  0.843879 -0.253666  1.337123
2000-01-03  1.325679  0.046904  0.291343 -0.467489 -0.531110
2000-01-04 -0.189141 -1.346146  1.378533  0.887792  2.957479
2000-01-05 -0.232299 -0.853726 -0.078214 -0.158410  0.782468

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```